# How to patch iPhone Apps using IDA /pro?

Tags: iphone, ios, patch, ida

I am trying to patch my own programs which I created for this task.

Unfortunately, once I do really simple patches and send the App to my iPod touch, it crashes as soon as I launch the App.

I'm using IDA pro 6.2 with patching menu. I open my process using the ARM processor option.

Is it correct?

Comment: Is your iPod jailbroken?

Comment: You might want to post a crash log for more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the command line tool `ldone` on your iDevice before running it. 
There can be some problems with the signatures in the mach-o file itself, that can be fixed by resigning the executable.